# Dynamic reloading of page with Chrome extension re-injects content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have an extension that injects content scripts when the tab is updated.
Main script:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    "use strict";
    const sendScriptToPage = function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
        if (changeInfo.status === "complete" && tab && tab.url && tab.url.indexOf("http") === 0) {
            console.log ("executeScript ");
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
                file: "content.js", allFrames: true
            });
        }
    };
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(sendScriptToPage);
});
```

Content script:

```
const Content = (function() {
    "use strict";
    console.log("Content");
    const makeRandomColor = function(){
        let c = '';
        while (c.length < 6) {
            c += (Math.random()).toString(16).substr(-6).substr(-1)
        }
        return '#'+c;
    };
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = makeRandomColor();
}
)();
```

It works fine when I reload a tab. However, when a tab is reloaded dynamically, the content script gets reloaded although it is already loaded in the tab. This shows in the log since const can't be re-declared.

Should not content scripts be unloaded when an update occurs? How can I know if a content script is already loaded or not?

A URL that shows this behaviour: 
http://www.prisjakt.nu/produkt.php?p=391945#rparams=ss=android

Typing something in the search field triggers the onUpdated event handler, but the content script is already in the page.

A test extension:
https://github.com/hawk-lord/chrome-test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A navigation would wipe the content scripts, but `onUpdated` can be triggered by many things.

The first that comes to mind is an iframe being loaded. The main page doesn't navigate but you do inject indiscriminately.

Many approaches are possible:

1. Make the content script more robust by checking for `Content` being defined before you do anything.
2. Listen to a different event, for example, various `webNavigation` API events. They will uniquely identify the frame they refer to.
3. Don't listen to events - always inject, and change your triggering logic (for instance, keep a flag in `chrome.storage`).

Comment: Thanks. The first approach seems to be the most convenient.

Comment: Interesting and learning from this question and trying to apply it to urgent matter I have with a chrome extension that needs page refresh in order for it to work.  https://superuser.com/questions/1320599/custom-chrome-tampermonkey-script-that-reloads-certain-assigned-pages-only-onc?